# How to use multiple OR,AND condition in Laravel query

Tags: sql, laravel-5.4

I'm new to laravel and I need help for query in laravel

My Custom Query: (Return Correct Result)

```
  $centerid=$_POST['inputCenterStatus'];
  $courseid=$_POST['inputCourseStatus'];

  $sql1="SELECT * FROM xxstudentregistrationxx 
        WHERE 
        status='active'
        AND
        ('$centerid'=''  OR centerid='$centerid')
        AND
        ('$courseid'='' OR courseid='$courseid')";
```

Comment: What database are you using ? MySQL ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
use DB;

public function get_registrations(Request $request){

      if($request->has('inputCenterStatus')){
         $centerid=$request->input('inputCenterStatus');
        }else{
         $centerid='';
       }


        if($request->has('inputCourseStatus')){
            $courseid=$request->input('inputCourseStatus');
        }else{
           $courseid='';
        }

        $results=DB::table('xxstudentregistrationxx')
        ->where('status','active')
        ->where('centerid',$centerid)
        ->where('courseid',$courseid)
        ->get();
        return response()->json($results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query builder conditional Clauses visit [Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#conditional-clauses)
.I hope you get help.